# Jasmine function or variable to check that all declared 'expect' functions have been called?

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am writing some async tests around Observables. My tests were passing, but I realised that was only because some of the `expect` matchers were actually not being called at all. Below is an example of one of these.

Is there a clever way to check that all `expect` functions have been called?
I'm aware I can add counts etc around it,  but want to know if there is a Jasmine way of doing it.

```
let count = 0;
let t0 = performance.now();

let sub = observable.subscribe((items) => {
    // before data initialized
    if (count === 0) {
        expect(items.length).toBe(0);
    }
    // after dataInitialized()
    if (count > 0) {
        expect(items.length).toBe(2);
        sub.unsubscribe();
        let t1 = performance.now();
        console.log('dataInitialize() took: ' + (t1 - t0) + ' milliseconds');
    }
    count++;
});
```

My test is like:

```
describe( 'asdf', () => {
   it('should initializeData()', async(() => {
       const wasPromiseCreated = contentfulService.initializeData();
       expect(wasPromiseCreated).toBeTruthy();
   }));

 it('should initializeData()', async(() => {
       const wasPromiseCreated = contentfulService.initializeData();
       expect(wasPromiseCreated).toBeTruthy();
   }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Jasmine way is a done callback, which is passed to the test function by the framework and once called signals everything has been executed. You could make a call to it according to a counter

```
it('is async', function(done) {
  // run assertions that increment counter and if (counter == #assertion) { done() }
});
```

Comment: Never used async to wrap a test. My hint is to use a normal function with async code inside it and call done when needed. There is an issue about using async listed on GitHub with useful infos: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1320